# Select Range of Cells, Save in set folder with pre-set name as PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to export a range of cells to a pdf and save it with a pre-set name to a set folder. The code I'm using only  will create a pdf and ask where I want to save it.  Any suggestions?

```
Sub ExcelToPDF()  

    Range("A11:D57").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:="C:\Documents\Plantwide\Document Managerment Control\File Name", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.  Below is the correct code:

```
Sub ExcelToPDF()

   Dim myFilename As String
   myFilename = "C:\Documents\Plantwide\Document Managerment Control\" & Range("B3") & " - " & Format(Range("B1"), "mm.dd.yyyy") & " - Final Report"

   Range("A11:D57").Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=myFilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```